# why I can't get my onChange/onBlur handler work on custom component (reactjs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why I can't get my onChange handler work on child custom component? did I miss something. Can you guys help me with solutions, if there's best practice to do this can you tell me.
thanks.

Sample code:

```
var TextBox = React.createClass ({
 getDefaultProps: function() {
     return {
         className: 'input-box'
     };
 },

 render() {
     return (
        <input type="text" />
    );
 }
});

var Dashboard = React.createClass({
 handleChange() {
  alert('test');
 }

 render() {

     return (
         <div>
             <h1>Components</h1>
             <label>Input Box</label><br/>
             <TextBox onBlur={this.handleChange} type="text" placeholder="hints (optional)"/>
         </div>
     )
 }
});
//ReactDOM.render goes here...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass along the event handlers as props all the way to the input component. As it is, your `input` has no event bindings setup.

An easy way to ensure all of your props are getting passed down to the innermost child is to use [the spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to pass all of your props in your `TextBox` component down to the child.

So, your `TextBox` component render function would look like:

```
 render() {
   return (
     <input { ...this.props } type="text" />
   );
 }
```

And that's it! All the props you pass to `<TextBox />` will make their way to the `<input>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a callback to get the changes in parent component

try as below,

```
class TextBox extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <input onBlur={this.props.callBack} type="text" />
    );
  }
}
class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const handleChange = () => {
      console.log('---');
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Components</h1>
        <label>Input Box</label><br/>
        <TextBox callBack={handleChange} type="text" placeholder="hints (optional)"/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

React.render(
  <Dashboard />,
  document.getElementById('react_example')
);
```